# Can't get transclude data binding working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I just made an example of how I am trying to use transclude data binding. Well, after binding an object (message) from controller scope its "undefined" in directive's link function.

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myAppController', function($scope)
            {
                $scope.message = { text: 'hello'}
            });

            angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective', function() {
                return {
                        restrict: 'E',
                        template: "<div><div ng-transclude></div></div>",
                        transclude: true,
                        scope: { message: "=" },
                        link: function (scope) {
                            // Its undefined here
                            console.log(scope.message);
                        }
                    };
            })
        </script>

    </head>

    <body ng-controller="myAppController">
        <my-directive>
            {{message.text}}
        </my-directive>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks

**[EDIT]**

Maybe I have not been too clear. Actually my code is kinda:

**Home.html**

Sorry, maybe I have not been too clear. Actually my code is **KINDA**:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script>
                angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myAppController', function($scope)
                {
                    $scope.model = { id: 100, name: "name"}
                });

                angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective', function() {
                    return {
                            restrict: 'E',
                            templateUrl: "Modal.html",
                            transclude: true,
                            scope: { model: "=" },
                            link: function (scope) {
                                // Its undefined here
                                console.log(scope.model);
                            }
                        };
                })
    </script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="myAppController">
    <my-directive>
        <div>
            id:<input type="text" ng-model="model.id" />
            name:<input type="text" ng-model="model.name" />
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="doIt()">do something</button>
        </div>
    </my-directive>
</body>
</html>
```

**Modal.html**

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Edit modal</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div ng-transclude>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="btnModalGravar()">Gravar</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="btnModalCancelar()">Cancelar</button>
</div>
```

Im just wondering why "console.log(scope.model)" returns "undefined" in directive's link function after using scope: { model: "=" }

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective', function() {
                return {
                        restrict: 'E',
                        template: "<div><div ng-transclude></div></div>",
                        transclude: true,
                        scope: { message: "=" },
                        link: function (scope) {
                            }
                    };
            })

//Html
 <my-directive message="message">
            {{message.text}}
        </my-directive>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to pass some data to directive **it's not a translusion but an isolated scope**. You've almost got it. Just use your directive like this:

```
<body ng-controller="myAppController">
    <my-directive message="message"></my-directive>

    <!-- This way you're referencing your $scope.message object, so it's like you've had:
    <my-directive message="{text: 'hello'}"></my-directive>
    -->
</body>
```

**Transclusion** is used to pass not some data but some **markup** (i.e. html, other directives).

If you want to use transcluded content inside your linking function, you should use it as a 5th parameter of this function, like this:

```
// Directive excerpt
return {
        ...
        transclude: true,
        link: function(scope, el, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
            var transcluded = transclude();
            console.log(transcluded);
        }
    };

// View excerpt
<my-directive message="message">
   <span>{{ message.text }}</span>
</my-directive>
```

Comment: Tomek, my code is more complex than this example, I just wondering why after using:

    scope: { message: "=" }

I cannot get it in link function using transclude

Comment: `scope.message` in your linking function references en object which you should pass as a value to a `message` parameter in your directive. Because you don't set such object (there is no `message` attribute when you write your directive in html code), your `scope.message` is in fact not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at **Isolating the Scope of a Directive** section in angular documentation [Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)